# Powershell script to compare two csv columns from two csv files

Tags: powershell-5.1

Hello everyone I need help creating a script in powershell that will take 1 column from 2 different csv files and out put the matches.

Both files have several columns but I'm only interested in the first one, under the name Computer Name, since they contain the names of computers.

**file1.csv**

Computer Name, useless info, useless info

comp1, info,info

comp45, info,info

comp33, info,info

comp47, info,info

**File2.csv**

Computer Name, useless info, useless info

comp2, info,info

comp45, info,info

comp8, info,info

comp47, info,info

**I need the output to be something like:**

matching computer

comp45

comp47

**I tried this so far:**

to get only the first column of each file, which give me:

Computer Name

---

Computer Name

comp1

comp45

comp33

comp47

$CSV1 = Import-Csv 'File1.csv' | -Header 'Computer Name'

$CSV2 = Import-Csv 'File2.csv' | -Header 'Computer Name'

ForEach ($name in $CSV1)
{
if ($name -eq $CSV2) {

```
    Write-Output $name
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated